# DefaultCellStyle format is not applied when DataGridView is bound

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, cell-formatting

I have a code that binds datagridview to datatable through a binding source:

```
_bind.DataSource = Table;
lGrid.DataSource = _bind;
```

In DataBindingComplete event i set the DefaultCellStyle for some columns:

```
void lGrid_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.Reset)
        lGrid.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "+#,##0;-#,##0;0";
}
```

At this point the Table is still empty. So later when row is added to the table and it reflects in DataGridView nicely, for some reason the format is not applied to the cell of column 0.

I checked the format inside CellFormatting event:

```
private void lGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ColumnIndex == lGrid.Columns[0].Index)
    {
        string s1 = lGrid.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format;
        string s2 = lGrid[0, args.RowIndex].Style.Format;
    }
}
```

and s1 returns me a correct format, but s2 is just an empty string.

Can you please advise what i am doing wrong, and how to get my cell formatted.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try formatting the cell style in the [CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event.

```
private void lGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs args) 
{
    if (args.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        args.Value = // format Value here
        args.FormattingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried setting lGrid[0, args.RowIndex].Style.Format = "+#,##0;-#,##0;0" inside CellFormatting but it doesnt work

Comment: @jfs Yes definitely works on a datagrid which is not bound to any table and updates directly.

Comment: @jfs Thanks for an idea, unfortunately that didnt work. In fact, when i checked args.CellStyle.Format before doing assignment args.CellStyle.Format = "+#,##0;-#,##0;0", it is actually already equal to it. But still doesnt show on DataGridView.

Comment: @Anya Can you paste the updated code? What is the value of `args.Value` after you formatted it?

Answer (score 2):

This may caused by DataTable Columns datatype is set to string(by default).

So you can change the DataTable Columns datatype to numeric:

1. When create the DataTable with columns

   ```
   Table.Columns.Add(ColumnName,typeof(double));
   ```
2. Change the date type later

   ```
   Table.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(decimal);
   ```

Comment: this was my issue.   but i was using designer, binding the dgv to a datasource.. so just go to your dataset's DataTable in Designer, select the column, and in the properties window, set the datatype to System.Double