# DefaultCellStyle number format doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I Have a `Datagridview` Import data with below Query:

```
dt1 = dc.RunQuery("SELECT   dbo.Payment.[Date], dbo.Payment.id FROM dbo.Payment INNER JOIN dbo.Moein ON dbo.Payment.FK_MoeinCode = dbo.Moein.MoeinCode ORDER BY dbo.Payment.[Date] ASC");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("2", "Detail");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("3", "X");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("4", "Y");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("5", "Remain");
```

And More ...

In end of code I use below code:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,#";
dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,#";
dataGridView1.Columns[5].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,#";
```

But This Doesn't Work :(

I Want Columns 3,4,5 Like This `111,555`.

Comment: Use CellFormatting event to format cells. Check this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658287/defaultcellstyle-format-is-not-applied-when-datagridview-is-bound

Answer (score 0):

You added some unbound columns to `DataGridView` using only name and header text. In such case, the column doesn't have any [`ValueType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx) and so formatting will not apply to it's value. So you should set a `ValueType` for those unbound columns.

To show a numeric format which shows thousand separator and some digits after decimal points (for example 2 digits) you can use `N2` format.

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
{
    ValueType = typeof(decimal),
    Name = "Column1",
    HeaderText = "Column One"
});
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Column1"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
```

This way the column shows data like: `12,345.67`

Comment: tried this but its work only in first row other rows still normal

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do specific to first row. It works properly for that column in all rows. To test the solution just put the exact code in `Load` event handler of the form in a clean form, you don't need any other code.

Comment: @user2588132 It seems the post answer your question. you can accept an answer by click on check mark near the answer. Also when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also vote for the answer by click on up arrow near the post. It's not compulsory at all, but it's common, reasonable and recommended. For more information about how does accepting answers work see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow).